# JSON-LD schema won't validate in SDTT

Tags: schema, json-ld

I've spent hours on this without solution. I'm having a terrible time identifying and correcting an error when validating in Google SDTT. After dozens of revisions, I continue to get "Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration" error.   I'd appreciate if someone will take a look, make the needed corrections or show me what I'm overlooking. Here's the code snippet >>  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HNJgZrGa7_F6-7FuGCbL2Y0vFPGsX7MQ

Comment: You have to include the relevant code in your question (the toolbar has a button for code formatting, or mark everything and press Ctrl+k to indent). Ideally you would include a minimal example, i.e., remove everything that’s not relevant for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top sameAs is a bit mixed up. I suspect you wanted to quote every URL and drop the last comma. e.g.

```
"sameAs" : [ "https://plus.google.com/100804793716209856515", "https://plus.google.com/115455274861158767219", "https://www.facebook.com/pg/TallentRoofingInc/about/", "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tallent-roofing-mckinney-2", "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tallent-roofing-melissa", "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tallent-roofing-el-paso-2", "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tallent-roofing-alpine", "https://www.yelp.com/biz/tallent-roofing-artesia" ]
```

Your graph is an array, but does to some bad closing of }s so it directly includes properties. Remove the } on the line before "aggregateRating" and add one to the line after "reviewCount".

```
,
"aggregateRating" : 
{
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue" : "4.9",
    "ratingCount": "57",
    "reviewCount": "53"
    }},
```